# Power supply broken?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test a power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/23788/how-to-test-a-power-supply)

I was switching internal hard drives while the computer was still running and then the computer shut down and won't boot now. I am thinking I may have shorted the power supply, but I have no spare one to test it. Are there any tricks to make sure it is broken before I go and order a new one?