# ATX 12V too low?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx

Im noob at pc's but is 3.20V too low for ATX +12V?
CPUID Hardware Monitor readings:

```
CPU VCORE - Value: 1.49V; Min: 1.46V; Max: 1.51;
ATX +3.3V - Value: 3.19V; Min: 3.18V; Max: 3.19V;
ATX +5V - Value: 5.15V; Min: 5.12V; Max: 5.20V;
ATX +12V - Value: 3.20V; Min: 3.20V; Max: 3.20V;
```

My PSU is 300 watt.

**Update**

```
Motherboard Name - Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF
CPU Type - Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)
CPU Alias - Northwood
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a little?  Make, model of PSU and motherboard, more of that 'quote' from CUID, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info...  Wow, yeah, I think something's not being read right. If your 12V is at 3v your HDD shouldn't even spin up.

Comment: What values are shown in the BIOS "PC Health" area?

Comment: I have HP motherboard and the bios is hewlet packard, there is no "PC Health" area.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you/CPUID are not looking at or reporting the status of one of the 3.3V lines?  I ask because, yes, 3V is WAY too low for a 12V line.

So low, that I wouldn't expect your computer be running if it was actually at that voltage. :)

Check out this SU question and answers: [How to test a power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/23788/how-to-test-a-power-supply)

It provides some ideas on how to determine if the PSU lines are working and such.  Specifically the answers about the [PSU tester](https://superuser.com/questions/23788/how-to-test-a-power-supply/23793#23793) and using a [multi-meter to test the individual lines](https://superuser.com/questions/23788/how-to-test-a-power-supply/23790#23790) are probably worth looking into.

**Edit:**

Also check for updated chipset driver for your motherboard, as the CPUID HW Monitor depends on an SMBus (System Management Bus) driver to interface with the sensors, and many of the SMBus interfaces in the Northwood P4 era were still pretty sketchy.

Comment: I will upgrade PSU, because I need 400 watts for ATI Radeon HD 4560 :)

Comment: What can happen?

Comment: Upgrading the PSU is probably a good idea for the new video card, but CPUID's HW Monitor still may read that line wrong, because I think it's a misread of the sensors by CPUID (try a newer version of CPUID?), or the sensors are being reported wrong by your motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect with the 12V line reading at 3V that the first problem would be your system not booting.

Please reboot your system, press whatever keys necessary to get into your BIOS and look for a section named either "Monitoring" or "PC Health" and check what values are there.

It may well be that those tools that you are using are reading the wrong sensors and so are confusing your 12V line with your 3V line.

Comment: There aren't "Monitoring" sections in my BIOS.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that your motherboard is a branded HP mobo.  It may well be that you don't have a section detailing the voltages.  I know my Dell one doesn't which is a bit annoying.  Check under the "Advanced" and "power" pages just to be sure...